# An Example for "no-function-constructor-with-string-args" rule at TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, rule, tslint

The explanation found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib) is very short:

> Do not use the version of the Function constructor that accepts a string argument to define the body of the function

maybe also for the rule `missing-optional-annotation` too:

> A parameter that follows one or more parameters marked as optional is not itself marked optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best example is probably the one used in the test suite for tslint.

```
var f = new Function("doSomething()");
```

This would cause a violation of the `no-function-constructor-with-string-args` rule.

For the `missing-optional-annotation`, in the following example:

```
constructor(requiredArg1, optionalArg2?, requiredArg3) {}
```

The second parameter is optional, but the third is not. This is not allowable, and would generate a violation.